# Excel VB to QTP 11 script convertion issue

Tags: shell, excel, qtp, vba

I have written script in Excel VBA and it is working fine, now I am trying to covert the same to QTP 11.0 - however facing some issue.

---

Updated Question based on suggestion by Xiaofu -

What is the VBA - shell function equivalent in QTP 11?

And below is **QTP 11 Script**:

```
Extern.Declare micHwnd, "OpenProcess", "kernel32", "OpenProcess", micLong, micLong, micLong
Extern.Declare micHwnd, "WaitForSingleObject", "kernel32", "WaitForSingleObject", micLong, micLong
Extern.Declare micHwnd, "CloseHandle", "kernel32", "CloseHandle", micLong

Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Const STATUS_PENDING = &H103
Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = &H102
Const INFINITE = &HFFFFFFFF


Public Function test_exe()

Dim argStr

    argStr = "cmd.exe /c " + Chr(34) & "plink.exe -load " + Chr(34) + session_name + Chr(34) + " -l " + Chr(34) + login_id + Chr(34) + " -pw " + Chr(34) + dns_pwd + Chr(34) + " -m " + Chr(34) + cmd_dir + "commands.txt" + Chr(34) + " >> " + Chr(34) + log_dir & log_filename + Chr(34) + Chr(34)
    exeCount = Run_Test(argStr, log_dir + log_filename)

End Function


Public Function Run_Test(exeStr, ByVal logFile)
Dim pid, ExitEvent
Dim lineStr
Dim okFlg
Dim hProcess

exeCount = "0"
okFlg = 0

pid = shell(exeStr, vbHide)

hProcess = Extern.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid)
ExitEvent = Extern.WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 15000)
Extern.CloseHandle(hProcess)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logFile, ForWriting, True)
Do
    f.writeLine lineStr
    If InStr(1, lineStr, "/home/") > 0 Then okFlg = okFlg + 1
    exeCount = "1"
Loop Until EOF(3)
f.close

If okFlg >= 1 Then
    Run_Test = okFlg
Else
    Run_Test = -1
End If

End Function
```

Error that I am getting is on line "`**pid = shell(exeStr, vbHide)**`" - "**Object doesn't support this property or method: 'shell'**"

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: For the sake of clarity in the question you could probably get rid of most of that code. You're really just asking "what is the UFT/QTP equivalent of the 'shell' function from VBA?" or "how do I start a process in UFT/QTP and get the process ID?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you make use of the DotNetFactory to access all that .NET goodness:

```
Dim csProcess
Set csProcess = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Diagnostics.Process")
Dim myProcess
Set myProcess = csProcess.Start("notepad.exe")
MsgBox myProcess.Id
```

If you are not familiar with or don't have access to the MSDN documentation, here is an example with command-line arguments:

```
Dim SystemProcess
Set SystemProcess = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Diagnostics.Process")

Dim processStartInfo
Set processStartInfo = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo")

processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
processStartInfo.Arguments = "/c notepad.exe"
Dim myProcess
Set myProcess = SystemProcess.Start(processStartInfo)
msgbox myProcess.Id
```

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion - but getting error - "`External object System.Diagnostics.Process::Start has thrown the following exception:
The system cannot find the file specified
Line (85): "Set myProcess = csProcess.Start(exeStr)`""

Comment: @Bhavin-Krishna See the extra code sample for how to deal with command-line arguments and the Process class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx