# How to execute plink with file containing commands thru QTP 11?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, qtp, plink

Need help in executing plink thru QTP 11 - also it should wait for command to finish - I have so far tried till below - but getting error:

```
Public Function test_exe()

Dim argStr

    argStr = "cmd.exe /c " + Chr(34) & "plink.exe -load " + Chr(34) + session_name + Chr(34) + " -l " + Chr(34) + login_id + Chr(34) + " -pw " + Chr(34) + dns_pwd + Chr(34) + " -m " + Chr(34) + cmd_dir + "commands.txt" + Chr(34) + " >> " + Chr(34) + log_dir & log_filename + Chr(34) + Chr(34)
    exeCount = Run_Test(argStr, log_dir + log_filename)

End Function


Public Function Run_Test(exeStr, ByVal logFile)
Dim pid, ExitEvent
Dim lineStr
Dim okFlg
Dim hProcess

exeCount = "0"
okFlg = 0

'pid = shell(exeStr, vbHide)

Dim csProcess
Set csProcess = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Diagnostics.Process")
Dim myProcess
Set myProcess = csProcess.Start(exeStr)
pid = myProcess.Id

hProcess = Extern.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid)
ExitEvent = Extern.WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 15000)
Extern.CloseHandle(hProcess)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logFile, ForWriting, True)
Do
    f.writeLine lineStr
    If InStr(1, lineStr, "/home/") > 0 Then okFlg = okFlg + 1
    exeCount = "1"
Loop Until EOF(3)
f.close

If okFlg >= 1 Then
    Run_Test = okFlg
Else
    Run_Test = -1
End If

End Function
```

Error: "External object System.Diagnostics.Process::Start has thrown the following exception: The system cannot find the file specified Line (85): "Set myProcess = csProcess.Start(exeStr)""

Comment: Please see your original question where I have updated with the answer to this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Excel VB to QTP 11 script convertion issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241211/excel-vb-to-qtp-11-script-convertion-issue)